# New installation, no stylesheets [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, installation, magento-community

I've just installed Magento CE 2.0.1 on a hosted domain.  But the stylesheets, images, etc. aren't working.  All I see is text.  This page from the Magento site[1](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_no-styles.html) suggests a solution but it seems to require access to the command line and some technical skills, neither of which I have.  Is there any other way to fix this problem--other than with access to the command line?

==========I'm adding the answer I got from my host's tech support:

The directory that holds the site images lacked readable permissions. They were set to 770. We changed them recursively to 775 (via your Control Panel's File Manager section), and the images display now. The directory in question is:

/home/sundheit/www/www/pub/static/frontend

The Magento developers recommend permissions 660 for files and 770 for directories. However, that is a problem when running Magento 2.0 on a shared hosting environment. You can use the File Manager in your hosting Control Panel to update the permissions of your files, if necessary.

You can also search the Internet for alternative solutions offered by other Magento 2.0 users. For example:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2412

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a non-technical solution for a technical problem

Comment: I've clarified that I am asking for a technical solution - just one using tools that I have access to, i.e. a solution that does not require access to the command line.

Comment: Installing and maintaining a Magento 2 installation without access to the command line is nearly impossible at the current state. Good to see that your hosting support could help you out, but running Magento on shared hosting is something I would strongly advice against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. As I understood Magento2 needs specific rewrite settings, because static content is loaded from pub/static, so you need to check that your Apache loads .htaccess rules or that your Nginx rewrite for static files work. You can find both .htaccess and nginx.conf.sample in the root Magento folder.

Also, you need to check if your webserver has rights to create files in pub/static folder, then everything should work.

You don't need command line acces, you can ask your hosting provider to check what I wrote above depending on what web-server you have. You can give them link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html so they can confirm that hosting configured in a right way, on this page they can find web-server configuration examples.